# Voltage calculator - Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Anglais

I would like to calculate by retrieving data in a textbox but it gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/#####/Desktop/Python/Calculateur_U_R_I/App_main.py", line 43, in <module>
    exe_button = Button(height=1, width=20, text='Exécuter', command=Calc())
  File "C:/Users/#####/Desktop/Python/Calculateur_U_R_I/App_main.py", line 15, in Calc
    result = text_label_1.get * text_label_2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'method' and 'Text'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And the code is :

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Text

help(tkinter.Text.get)

window = Tk()

window.minsize(1200, 400)

def Calc():
    result = text_label_1.get * text_label_2
    print(str(result))


text_label_1: Text = Text(window, height=1, width=10)
text_label_1.grid(row=0, column=2)

text_label_2 = Text(window, height=1, width=10)
text_label_2.grid(row=0, column=4)

name_label_1 = Label(window, height=1, width=10, text='Tension')
name_label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

name_label_2 = Label(window, height=1, width=10, text=' = ')
name_label_2.grid(row=0, column=1)

name_label_3 = Label(window, height=1, width=10, text=' * ')
name_label_3.grid(row=0, column=3)

name_label_4 = Label(window, height=1, width=10, text=' = ')
name_label_4.grid(row=0, column=5)

name_label_5 = Label(window, height=1, width=10)
name_label_5.grid(row=0, column=6)

exe_button = Button(height=1, width=20, text='Exécuter', command=Calc())
exe_button.grid(row=1, column=5)

window.mainloop()
```

---

```
Ok but what is the index1 ? 




    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/#####/Desktop/Python/Calculateur_U_R_I/App_main.py", line 47, in <module>
    exe_button = Button(height=1, width=20, text='Exécuter', command=Calc())
  File "C:/Users/#####/Desktop/Python/Calculateur_U_R_I/App_main.py", line 17, in Calc
    r = int(text_label_1.get())
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'
```

Comment: Sorry for the errors of the orthographs I'm French

Comment: You have to say `result = int(text_label_1.get('1.0','end-1c')) * int(text_label_2.get('1.0','end-1c')) `

Comment: It is better to use `Entry` instead of `Text` widget with 1 row height.

Answer (score 0):

`text_label_1.get * text_label_2`  - the issue is that `text_label_1.get` is a method (function) while `text_label_2` is a Text. You need to get the text from both labels, convert to numbers and do the math

Comment: Might be better if you include code in to show, how to, too.

Comment: Split the problem into few sub problems. 1) How to get the text from `tkinter Text` 2) Once 1 is done - how to convert a string to number?

Comment: I wasn't asking explanation for me, I was asking to provide a better answer with code so OP can understand.

Comment: OK. This is why I break the challange into smaller challenges that the OP  can digest

Comment: I thought we were supposed to provide answers and not challenges.